# Java LWJGL - How can I create proper maps using heightmaps?

Tags: java, lwjgl, terrain, heightmap

So right now I am using greyscale heightmaps to load the height of the terrain to my game. So far I cannot seem to create a heightmap in which I can actually control where land masses are etc. I just get something like this:

[image]

These hills are completely random and generated by a greyscale cloud effect in GIMP.. There has to be a way in which I can generate heightmaps after creating a map in a program or something. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: Is this question related to Java or LWJGL? Also, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might find better answers, since most people here aren't game developers.

Comment: Sorry I realized there isnt much lwjgl or java in here, but it needs to work with my java LWJGL library so I figured Id put it in. Thanks for the reference I didnt know there was such a site! This helps a lot :P